# problem strtok in c++

Tags: c++

i have a problem in strtock in c++
i need to read the follwing line from file

**6:00,6:20,6:40,7:00,7:20,7:40,8:00,8:50,9:40,10:30,11:20,12:00**
the length of the line is unknow(i dont know how many arguments i have);

i try to do this function:

```
void RailwayLine::initilizeLoz(char line[1024])
 {

  char * pch;
  char * timeReader;
  Hour *hour;
  char * pch2=NULL;
  int time;
  int minute;
  char line2[1024];
  strcpy(line2,line);
  pch = strtok (line2,",");
 while (pch != NULL)
   {
    delete pch2;
    pch2= new char(strlen(pch)+1);
    if(pch2!=NULL)
   strcpy(pch2,pch);
    timeReader = strtok (pch2,":");
    time=atoi(timeReader);
    timeReader = strtok (NULL,":");
    minute=atoi(timeReader);
    hour=new Hour(time,minute);

           this-> UpdateLoz((*hour));

             pch=strtok(NULL,",");


   }


 }
```

but  it didn't works. itj reads only the first argument (7:10)!
what can be the froblem?
how can i improve my code?
thank you

Comment: That code has a memory leak. `pch2` will not get deleted after the last iteration. Why would you delete it at the beginning of the loop instead of the end, when you're done using it?

Comment: There is no point in checking for `NULL` after `new` ing memory. If `new` fails it'll throw `std::bad_alloc` exception and the `NULL` check is never reached. If you want to check for `NULL`, pass `std::nothrow` to the `new` call; otherwise replace the `NULL` check with a `try-catch` instead.

Comment: If in C++ why not use a string ?

Comment: man strtok ... BUGS: Avoid using these functions.

Comment: thank you for your answers it is for project in the universtiy and i been told not to use string!:\

Answer (score 6):

You can't have nested `strtok` calls because the function keeps internal state between calls. Use `strtok_r` instead.

Comment: Or `strtok_s` if you're using Visual C++

Answer (score 2):

The absolute best way you could improve your code is to stop using `stroke` and use something that leverages the power of the language you're using.  Boost has a tokenizer and other libraries that might actually meet your needs better (like regex).

The stroke in `stroke` isn't the fun kind; it's the kind you get in your brain.  Terrible, terrible function that's design dates back to the dark ages of programming.  It's got severe and permanent issues that render it not just obsolete, but dangerous...as you are seeing here.  Stop trying to build things by tyeing rocks and sticks together.  Come into the modern age where we've got forges and robotics.  Save your brain!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use a [Boost Split](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/string_algo/usage.html#id2571159) or [Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html) algorithm. But if you don't have Boost available, you could do something like this:

```
std::istringstream iss(line);
std::string departure;
while (getline(iss, departure, ','))
{
    // departure has one time in it;
    // do what you will with it
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can nest the strtok as you have done - when you fire up the search for the ":" it forgets about the previous instance you had going for picking out the comma separated items.

Answer (score 0):

This would do the job.

```
 
void tokenize( std:: string stringToTokenize ) {
```

```
    char* pch = new char [ (stringToTokenize.length()) + 1 ];

    std:: strcpy( pch, stringToTokenize.c_str() ) ;

    pch = std:: strtok( pch, "," ) ;

    std::cout << std::endl ;

    while( pch != NULL ) {

    std::cout << pch << std::endl ;
    pch = strtok( NULL, "," ) ;

    }
```

}

int main( int argc, const char* argv[] ) {

`std:: string s1 ;
std:: getline( std::cin, s1 ) ; 
tokenize( s1 ) ; 
return 0 ;`

}